# c++ function return NULL string reference

Tags: c++, reference, null

I have a function has a return type of `std::string&` and how do I return a NULL `string&` if no condition matches in the function?

```
std::string& SomeClass::getSomething()
{
     if(){...}
     else if(){...}
     // return a NULL
}
```

Comment: You can't. There is no such thing as a NULL `std::string`. You need to re-think your approach.

Comment: Maybe return an empty string?

Comment: You could return a pointer in stead of a reference, then you could return a NULL pointer.

Comment: What about throwing an exception?

Comment: The is also [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: I'm honestly curious what the OP thinks the *caller* of this thing would look like.

Comment: Yes, C++ references are not like Java references. C++ refs are bound to an actually object of the reference's type when the ref enters the scope. As a side note, you want to be careful about object lifetimes when returning references from functions/methods -- e.g. just returning a reference will not "increase refcount" on it...

Comment: Yeah I understand how reference works now, I will use pointer instead, thanks guys!

Comment: Think on how you are going to manage the lifetime of the string before returning a pointer. Several posters below mention smart pointers. Recommend reading up on them.

Comment: @user4581301 Presumably there is nothing to be done, as with the reference. I don't see the need for a smart pointer here, if the intent really is to refer to something owned by something else.

Comment: True enough. I was projecting returning a `new`ed pointer on OP's code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C++ references cannot be null.

If you are returning a reference to an object whose lifetime is not tied to the scope of the function call, like a data member, you can safely return a raw pointer (I would recommend a *pointer to const*).

```
std::string const* foo::bar() const {
    if (condition) {
        return &some_data_member;
    } else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

If not, the best solution is to use a wrapper type like [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) (or [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) in C++17). This not only allows you to return an optional object by value (which may be more performant), but is also [self-documenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code).

```
std::optional<std::string> foo::bar() const {
    if (condition) {
        return "hello, world";
    } else {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could return a pointer, which can be null. However, returning a raw pointer raises the question of who is responsible for deleting the dynamically allocated string. In this case, returning a [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) would be the best option, as ownership is explicitly passed to the caller.

```
std::unique_ptr<std::string> foo::bar() const {
    if (condition) {
        return std::make_unique<std::string>("hello, world");
    } else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

Or even simpler, you could return an empty string, if this is possible in your case. And honestly, this is my preferred approach ([KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)).

```
std::string foo::bar() const {
    if (condition) {
        return "hello, world";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Given that in the original code, the returner owns the string being referred to, I think it would be fine to return a non-owning raw pointer. Returning a unique_ptr transfers ownership to the caller, which is a serious change in semantics WRT. the original code.

Comment: @juanchopanza Noted.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway you wouldn't return `NULL` but `nullptr`.
Also, you should be carefull with returning references from a function and make sure the reference referes to a valid, living object. returning reference to local object is wrong.

you can't return `nullptr` since `nullptr` is a pointer and `string&` is a reference - different types.

your options are:

1. throw an exception
2. use something like Optional classes (`boost::optional`, etc.)

personally, if I know there is a strong possibility the function may fail, I would pass the result to a reference type argument and return `bool` to indicate success of failure

```
bool SomeClass::getSomething(std::string& result)
{
     if(){result = "success 1"; return true; }
     else if(){result = "success 2"; return true; }
     return false.
}
```

Comment: The 1970s called...!

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet so when .Net gives you `TryParse`,`TryGetValue` it's cool and modern, but on C++ it's suddenly ancient and ugly?

Comment: When did I say `TryParse` and `TryGetValue` are "cool and modern"? (Hint: I didn't) (Another hint: those are ancient and ugly, too)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments by *juanchopanza*, you can't.

If you need to test for `NULL` you could re-think your approach using a smart pointer. For instance a `std::shared_ptr<std::string>`:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> SomeClass::getSomething()
{
     std::shared_ptr<std::string> stringPtr;
     if(){
         //...
         stringPtr = std::make_shared<std::string>("Whatever string goes here");
     }
     else if(){
         //...
         stringPtr = std::make_shared<std::string>("The other string...");
     }
     return stringPtr;
}
```

Then you could just test the `std::shared_ptr`with its implicit conversion to bool:

```
auto strReturnedPtr = someClassObj.getSomething();
if (strReturnedPtr)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Do not use new, but `stringPtr = make_shared ...`

Comment: Why shared_ptr? The only participants in this seem to be the caller and getSomething, and getSometing is out of the game at hand-over to caller.

Comment: @DieterLücking noted. Couldn't fix it before, I was getting the "Ooops something went wrong" with SO, weird.

Comment: @user4581301 Just gave an example with the `shared_ptr` to show usage with smart pointers, don't know the OP context. I should have also mentioned `unique_ptr` as already proposed in another answer. Anyway in retrospective, a smart pointer seems overkill in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Returning the empty string '' might make sense here.

From your code fragment I'd be wondering if you are peeking under the covers of the class to make a decision that the class itself should be making. See the Martin Fowler's article about "[Tell, don't Ask](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html)" which also refers to the original article on this by The Pragmatic Programmers.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.  What I did was to let the caller pass what to return in case the return has to be null:

```
string myFunc(string param1, string not_found_value) {

if (not_returning_null)
    return actual_string;
else
    return not_found_value;

}
```